# Ionic selected item is missing in dropdown when click another dropdow

Tags: angularjs, drop-down-menu, ionic-framework

I ve three dropdown in my page and all dropdown get the datas from web service. Everything is cool when page load. All dropdowns get the right datas when i open them.

But when i select one item from a dropdown then clik to other dropdown to select its item, first dropdown that i selected item is missing like i didnt select anything before. Could you help me about this problem please

```
<tr>
    <td>

        <select id="3089" ng-model="x.x" ng-options="x.y for x in listx track by x.x">
            <option value="">{{x.y}}</option>
        </select>

    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>

        <select id="3090" ng-model="x.x" ng-options="x.yfor x in listxx track by x.x">
           <option value="">{{x.y}}</option>
        </select>

    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>

        <select id="3091" ng-model="x.x" ng-options="x.yfor x in listxxx track by x.x">
            <option value="">{{x.y}}</option>
        </select>

    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: U defined all selects with the same ngModel: ng-model="x.x" That's why it behaves like this.

Comment: If you want write this commet as answer cause it works great. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have defined all select fields with the same [ngModel](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel):

```
ng-model="x.x"
```

Every change on any select will cause a change on `$scope.x.x`.

That's why it behaves like this :)

So you have to set different variables on each [ngModel](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel).